# Getting time since last custom field update in a jira groovy listener script?

Tags: java, groovy, listener, jira

**Some Background**

I'm using Jira 8 to do some automation of our workflow, with scriptrunner (heavily Java like) and I'm having trouble figuring out how to get the time in milliseconds, hours, etc since the last time the custom field was updated. I found the code below that seems to be able to get the history of the variable (which I modified a bit for testing)

**Code**

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.changehistory.ChangeHistoryManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.history.ChangeItemBean


if (issue.issueType.name == 'My Product' && issue.status.name == 'Review')
{
    String fieldName = 'Demo info'



    ChangeHistoryManager changeHistoryManager = ComponentAccessor.getChangeHistoryManager()

    List<ChangeItemBean> changeItem
    changeItem = changeHistoryManager.getChangeItemsForField(issue, fieldName)
    if (changeItems.size()> 0) 
    {
        log.debug('last updated')
        log.debug(changeItem.sort{it.getCreated()}.last().getCreated())
        }
        else 
        {
            log.debug(issue.getCreated())
        }
}
```

**Question**

I'm trying to figure out how to make this line `changeItem.sort{it.getCreated()}.last().getCreated()` and this line `log.debug(issue.getCreated())` return the time in milliseconds. But, I haven't been very successful at this.

I know this scripting language is heavily based on Java, but I'm not a Java programmer so I'm struggling to figure out how to approach this.

Any help would be appreciated. Some of the issue is the code on the web is very outdated, and I know Java has changed how they do time/date stuff.

**Bonus points explanation**

Bonus points if you can explain how to do it using the one of the more updated Calendar libraries `java.util.Calendar`

**Extra Credit**

Extra credit if you can explain how to get the current time in the issue as well. I technically need to get the time elapsed since the last field update, but have been unsuccessful at getting that information.

Comment: The `java.util.Calendar` class is the opposite of "more updated". That class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined by JSR 310. Specifically, `java.time.ZonedDateTime` replaces `GregorianCalendar` subclass. This has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I said I wasn't a Java developer. I appreciate your annoyance at my ignorance though. Very unhelpful comment.